# Откатить проект в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Возможно ли откатить проект в IDEA?. Больше часа изменял код во многих классах и теперь ничего не работает.

Comment: local history

Comment: обычно пользуются git/svn/hg или, для любителей, cvs. Начните ими пользоваться (рекомендую git/hg) и больше у Вас подобных вопросов не будет.

Comment: я думал local history только в eclipse есть, вообще да, любая vcs подойдет для этих целей

Comment: Писать код или рефакторить существующий, и за целый час ни разу не запустить тесты. Да ещё и вести разработку без VCS. Да вы программист-камикадзе, не иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Local history фича IDEA - запоминает все изменения для каждого файла, но она может быть выключена по умолчанию.
Для будущего чтобы не было таких проблем используйте систему контроля версий. IDEA работает со всеми популярными системами. 
Из личного опыта, git спас проект около 10 раз, так как комиты делаю после каждой фичи. Инфу теряю не большую. И ее легко написать заного.